# Wordpress ACF: Query with sub-field repeater date

Tags: php, wordpress, search, advanced-custom-fields

I want to perform a search in my wordpress site where I have a custom post (`cp_course`) with some  custom fields (`course_code`, `course_iteration`). `Course_iteration` custom field is a `Repeater` containing these date `sub_fields`: `course_iteration_start` and `course_iteration_start`.

So this is what I have tried so far:

```
// filter
function my_posts_where( $where ) {

    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'course_iterations_%", "meta_key LIKE 'course_iterations_%", $where);

    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');




$args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'cp_course', 'numberposts' =>-1,'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC', 's' => $searchterm,
        'meta_query' => 
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'   => 'course_code',
                    'value' => $code,
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'course_duration',
                    'value' => $duration,
                ),  
                array(
                    'key'   => 'course_iterations_%_course_iteration_start',
                    'compare' => 'between',
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'value' => array($date_from, $date_to),

                )
            )

    );


$course = get_posts($args);


<div class="page_title">
    <h3>Courses</h3>
</div>
<?php foreach ($course as $post):setup_postdata($post);?>
<a href="#"><?php the_title();?></a>

<?php endforeach;wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

But with no luck. Can anyone guide me on how to solve this? I've spent so many days on it without managing to get it to work and its so frustrating. If it's not easy is there a plugin that can achieve that?

Comment: Not sure how much further you got with this, but you need to use the `%` to `$` fix that is mentioned in the docs. Change `$where = str_replace("meta_key = 'course_iterations_%", "meta_key LIKE 'course_iterations_%", $where);` 
to 
`$where = str_replace("meta_key = 'course_iterations_$", "meta_key LIKE 'course_iterations_%", $where);` 
and `'key'   => 'course_iterations_%_course_iteration_start',` 
to 
`'key'   => 'course_iterations_$_course_iteration_start',`

Comment: Forgot to add the link to the documentation. Section four of this page: [link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/)

Answer (score 0):

ACF custom fields are not exposed, as far as I am aware, in default wp_queries, you might have a look at this in order to achieve what you need: https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/